# How to pass textbox values as parameter in crystal report in Visual Basic 2005

Tags: vb.net

`Form1` has a `button1` and a `texbox1`, when I click `button1`, `form2` will load with crystal report on it and display data that I put on `textbox1`. Already created Parameters Field `crTextBox` and put into crystalreport. How can I pass `textbox1.text` value to `crTextBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code inside Form2

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1

    Report1.SetParameterValue("crTextBox", Form1.TextBox1.Text)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a parameter fields of Crystal report for this....

1.Open Field Explorer window in Crystal report.

2.Go to Parameter Fields.

3.Right Click on "Parameter Fields"
        Click on "New"

4.In the pop-up window give a Name for your parameter and give its Data Type.Name is mytextBoxValue and Data Type is String.

5.A parameter field[mytextBoxValue] will be added under Parameter Fields...Drag this field to your report and place where you want to show your textbox value.

6.Now in the code behind file write the following code to pass your TextBox value to this Crystal report parameter field.

---

Dim txtValue As String=TextBox1.Text

Dim myReport As New CrystalReport1

myReport .SetParameterValue("mytextBoxValue", txtValue )

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like:

```
 Dim rpt as New ReportDocument
 'rpt.Load("file.rpt") ...
 'rpt.SetDatasource() ...
 rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("MyFormula").Text = textbox1.text
```

Comment: @denn and david it's beautiful. Shortest code to solve a very big problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    'this code works fine for me        

    Dim CrxReport As New cm_Detallado_Partes_vs
    Try
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrxReport

        'the formula must be the same as it is used in CR
        CrxReport.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tpresupuesto.codigo} = '18-0004'"

        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowExportButton = True
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = True
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = True

        CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(100)
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
```